# How to break while loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I want the inner *while loop* to be broken when the input data is 5, but if the input is other than 5, the loop will be executed again. In this code, the input value of each number I enter is printed as X = 1:

```
x = 1
while True:
    def state():
        x = input("Enter Your number:")

    while True:
        print(x)
        if x==5:
            print('x=5')
            break
        state()
```

In this code, I tried to solve the problem but it didn't work too.

```
condition = True
x = 1
while True:
    def state():
        x = input("Enter Your number:")

    while condition:
        print(x)
        if x==5:
            print('x=5')
            condition = False
        state()
```

Is there anyone to help me?

Comment: There are multiple problems here. 1) the scope of ``x`` in state() is limited to that function (better work with a return value or use the ``global`` keyword). 2) ``input`` returns a string and ``"5"`` is never equal to the number ``5``.

Answer (score 0):

- you are defining your function in while loop.
- also the scope of x in your function is local, return the value or use the input in while loop
- and the expression x==5 will never be true

try this:

```
    while True:
       x = input("Enter Your number:")
       if x=="5":
          print('x=5')
          break
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want your program to ask the user continuously to enter the number and if he enters 5, the loop breaks.

The `input` function stores the entered value as a string so you have to use `int()` to convert it to int.

You can use a single while loop to achieve this.
Try this:-

```
while True:
    x = int(input("Enter Your number:"))
    print(x)
    if x==5:
        print('x=5')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure the input is a number you should try to cast it to an int:

```
while True:
    inpt = input("Enter Your number:")
    try:
        x = int(inpt)
    except:
        print('Not a number.')
    print(f'x = {x}')
    if x==5:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you, It solved. But I edit x=='5' in your code.

Comment: @mehdializade Indeed, you are right. Feel free to select as helpful and select your answer of choice.